# change cpan install directory

Tags: 12.04, perl, cpan

I have tried to setup `cpan` on my `ubuntu 12.04` using:

```
sudo cpan
```

and it created a folder `perl5` in my `$HOME` folder. I would like to use a different directory such as `$HOME/.perl5` or somewhere in `/usr/local/lib` for the modules. Is it possible?

Comment: When running cpan for the first time, it appended the path settings to my `.bashrc` file as environment variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The destination to which CPAN installs modules can be changed by setting its options (run `o conf` in the CPAN shell):

```
makepl_arg         [INSTALL_BASE=/home/gokcehan/.perl5]
mbuildpl_arg       [--install_base=/home/gokcehan/.perl5]
```

To let CPAN and Perl search for modules in the given path, set the environment variable PERL5LIB:

```
PERL5LIB=/home/gokcehan/.perl5:/home/gokcehan/.perl5/$arch
```

where $arch is the output of

```
use Config;
print Config->{archname};
```

Comment: Can we do same but via `cpan` options?